# Show that $\int_2^{+ \infty} \frac{\log(t)^2}{t(t-1)}dt \leq 4$

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality, integral-inequality

I couldn't prove this inequality
$$
\int_2^{+ \infty} \frac{\log(t)^2}{t(t-1)}dt \leq 4
$$
I've tried integration by parts but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
\begin{align*}
 \int_2^\infty \frac{\ln^2 t}{t(t - 1)}\,\mathrm{d} t
 & \overset{t = 1/x} =
 \int_0^{1/2} \frac{\ln^2 x}{1 - x} \,\mathrm{d} x \\
 &\le \int_0^{1/2} \frac{\ln^2 x}{1 - 1/2} \,\mathrm{d} x\\
 &= 2\int_0^{1/2} \ln^2 x \,\mathrm{d} x\\
 &= \ln^2 2 + 2 + 2\ln 2\\
 &< 4.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick-and-dirty approach:

1. Show that $\sup_{t\geq 2} \frac{\log^2 t}{\sqrt{t}} = \frac{16}{e^2}$ (achieved at $t=e^4$). That can easily be done by differentiating the function $t\mapsto \frac{\log^2 t}{\sqrt{t}}$.
2. Compute $\int_2^\infty \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}(t-1)} = 2\operatorname{arcsinh} 1$
3. Observe that $\frac{32}{e^2}\operatorname{arcsinh} 1 < 4$.